# Excluding a subdomain from a rewrite

Tags: apache-2.4

I think this is pretty basic, but danged if I can get it to work!
I have a domain example.com, subdomain cloud.example.com.
I want to redirect everything EXCEPT cloud.example.com to an external site.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ "https\:\/\/some\.external\.site\/" [R=301,L]
```

Things seem to work OK using Firefox, but using iPhone, Chrome or Microsoft Edge just gets you a blank page, with "Not secure" and the example.com in the location bar.
Not even mentioning "cloud" anywhere, so it seems that it must be something in the conditions or rule that I'm messing up.
Any help??

Answer (score 1):

How about this -- if the condition http_host does not match *cloud* then redirect to https://some.external.site/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^cloud\. [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) https://some.external.site/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Awesome!  That works just as intended.  I did have the negation in place at one point, but was missing a little something.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Grindel Glad to hear that.